# Turbo C++: Generate object code for malloc function

Tags: c++, c, assembly, linker, tasm

I am using Turbo C++ 3.1.

I have some assembly modules that require C standard library's malloc.
So I in my .asm files I have:

```
extern _malloc:proc
```

I want to generate an object file which contains malloc().
In order to use the linker and build an executable file.
Example:

```
tasm /zi bmlib.asm  // create object file: bmlib.obj
tasm /zi bmlibt.asm // create object (which contains main program): bmlibt.obj
? //Generate object file for malloc: malloc.obj
tlink /v3 bmlibt bmlib malloc // link all modules
bmlibt.exe // Execute the program
```

Comment: If you want to use the runtime's `malloc()` you'll need to link in the runtime library (since `malloc()` certainly has it own set of dependencies). You'll also need to make sure that the runtime gets initialized appropriately. You might just find it easier to link your assembly files to a small C program that does nothing but call an entry point for your assembly language program. Or maybe implement a simple `malloc()`

Comment: Thanks. The C file tip is great. To implement my own malloc I would need to use interrupts to ask the OS for space, right?

Comment: That's probably one way to do it. I imagine there's a way to get the linker to set up the .exe headers so there's a pool of memory when the process is loaded, but it's been a long time since I've worked with MS-DOS so I can't give any details on how that might work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want Turbo C++'s `malloc` in an object file, you'll use `tlib` to extract that object file from the standard library. Offhand I don't remember the flag to give to `tlib` with any certainty, nor the name of the file for the standard library, but both should be fairly easy to find.

You don't really need to do this though: if you just use `tcc` on the command line, it will compile and link the modules you've used from the standard library, all automatically. You do just about need to use at least one file in C though -- `malloc` depends on some initialization that happens in the C startup code, so even if you link it successfully, without that startup code it won't actually work.

Comment: Yeah, I will use the C file tip. But, I still want to learn to do it all without needing C files, will try the tlib tip later.

Comment: @metroxylon: If you want a standard library that you can use in pure assembly, you might want to consider [Spontaneous Assembly](http://kevincrenshaw.com/spontaneous.htm). I used it back when it was new -- it's *quite* good.

Answer (score 1):

malloc() is part of the C (or C++) runtime library.  You might be able to tell your linker to link the C runtime (often called CRT) statically, but normally it's linked dynamically so that the size of your executable is smaller.  In any case, you don't generally have the option to get the runtime's malloc() implementation built into a separate object file.  If you implement your own version of it, of course, it would be part of your object file.  In that case, your implementation overrides the system's implementation.

So I guess what you should be looking for is some way to tell the linker you want to link with the C runtime library, either statically or dynamically.  Then your assembly object file should have access to it when it's linked into a final executable.